# Socket.io cross-domain issue - Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, socket.io

I have a website at a url (example.com) and am using node.js/socket.io to pass JSON into my webpage.  I'm currently receiving an error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:12003/socket.io/1//897026922693503087/?disconnect=1. Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

My node code looks like the following:

```
   var http = require('http');
   var mysqlClient = require('mysql').createClient({'user':'root','password':'XXXXXXXX'});

   mysqlClient.query('USE myDBName');

   var mysqlData;

   setInterval(function(){
       mysqlClient.query(
                      'SELECT number, page_id FROM dbTableName',
                      function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                          throw err;
                  }

                mysqlData = [];
           for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
               mysqlData[i] = results[i];
           }
       });  
   }, 1000);

   var io = require('socket.io').listen(12003);
   io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {

       console.log("New Connection: ", client.id); //log new connection

             client.emit('connection', client.id);//custom emit to let site know its connected
            client.on("requestNewData", function(data){
                client.emit('init', JSON.stringify(mysqlData));
       });

       client.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("Disconnected: ", client.id);
       });
   });
```

I've tried this line of code to fix the issue with no success:

```
          var io = require('socket.io').listen(12003, {origins: '*:*'});
```

I'm running on an Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu Ocelot.  My client side code is:

```
          <script src="http://example.com:12003/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:12003');
              socket.emit("requestNewData", {"nothing":"here"});
              ...
```

Since I'm just using a socket I don't think I can use 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' in my node code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The error I'm receiving is only on Chrome - from my understanding Chrome is more restrictive about cross-domain connections...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find as solution to this? I'm seeing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try just including the relative path for your socket.io on the client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com');
```

Comment: This didn't work... I now receive the following error: GET http://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined.  I think this is because it's looking on port 80 when my socket info is on port 12003.  Any other thoughts...?

Comment: ill take a look when i get home

Comment: Keep me posted whenever you get a chance... I still haven't been able to find a solution...